# Why isn't data from Route Handlers updated?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I was testing out the new Route Handlers in next `next 13.4.4` when I stumbled upon a problem. The data doesn't update at all, so if I change the text of the NextResponse the data shown on app/page.js remains the same. Here is the code:

```
async function getTodos() {
  const res = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/api');

  if (!res.ok) {
    throw new Error("Couldn't fetch data");
  };

  return res.json();
}

export default async function Home() {
  const todos = await getTodos();

  return (
    <main className='bg-neutral-900 text-white min-h-screen'>
      <div className="container mx-auto">
        <h1>Todo App</h1>
        <pre>
          { JSON.stringify(todos, null, 2) }
        </pre>
      </div>
    </main>
  )
}


// api/route.js
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";

export async function GET() {
  return NextResponse.json({ message: "Hello 1"})
}
```

Here the app/page.js shows `Hello 1` which is exactly what I want, but when I changed the /api/route.js text to 'Hello 2', the text on app/page.js still shows `Hello 1`. I tested the API by going to http://localhost:3000/api and there it shows `Hello 2`. I also tested it by using the VS Code extension `Thunder Client` which showed again `Hello 2`. However `app/page.js` still isn't working as expected. Can someone tell me how to fix this problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: Just set the fetch options to { cache: 'no-store' } and it will work fine.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).